How to convert clipping mask to an object which looks the same?
I am making some clipping mask from a drawing. I am starting from

and then have

How to "finalize" this object so that it was just collection of lines and look the same?

This is a commonly asked question lets try to make a authoritative answer.

How to "finalize" this object so that it was just collection of lines and look the same?

Depending on the definition of line that you are using the answer is either

you can not
Or you can

Lets explore you can not first:
Ok, so clipping mask is not a vector action. Its a rasterization boundary action. It kicks in when the image is made into pixels or printer rasters.
This means there are odd corner cases on printers where it does things that can not be had in any other way as it interacts with the halftoning process.

Image 1: The end cap is slanted, there is no line that has this property.
Okay, but you can do this for most cases though! So now for what you can do:
Instead you can expand your strokes into shapes (Object → expand). So each stroke is now a box, in essence making your file 4 times more complex per line. Then you can use pathfinder window intersect command.
No there is no builtin command to do this. It does not exactly do the same thing but its mostly the same. Rendering results may be slightly different though.

Image 2: You can expand your strokes then build new shapes out of that.
In practice this is painful since illustrator is designed in way that does not account for the need to ever do this.
There are cases where you need to do this like:
Illustrator: how to reproduce line art
But again painful as illustrator was not built to do this. Illustrator operates under the assumption everything is a filled area in the end...

Or, convert to filled objects and make a boolean operation?

@Rafael that would be the text between image 1 and image 2, yes.

Oh... Ok. Now I get the 4x complex line. P.D. I would only do that for things like a logo, not a random file, or even an illustration. On an illustration, I would prefer to have simple and editable lines.
